# Image content is same for different images uploaded

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-4.5, httppostedfile

When I am trying to upload pics, same pic is getting uploaded with different name

```
   HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 1; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];

                string filename = userPostedFile.FileName;
                string filepath = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + filepath);

}
```

Lets say I am upload images a.jpeg, b.jpeg and c.jpeg then in my upload folder I am seeing 
a.jpeg, b.jpeg and c.jpeg but they all look like a.jpeg

**EDIT1**
ASPX code

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:FileUpload  AllowMultiple="true" ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
          ......

 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line...

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + filepath);
```

Should be...

```
userPostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + filepath);
```

Comment: Perfect ! worked for me... :) +1 for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

That should be due to your html.

Look at your input html. Like below.

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" /> 
<input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" />
....
```

or file array

```
<input type="file" name="file[1]" id="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file[2]" id="file1" />
...
```

In your code, your input names are probably same. That is why your are getting the same file.

Comment: generated HTML looks like this *<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="FileUpload1" id="FileUpload1"  />* I have also updated my question with ASPX code